# UIViewController containing a flow of UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I am building a `UIViewController` (*outer viewController*) that contains another `UIViewController` (*inner viewController*). To do this I am using a container view. Now I want the inner viewController to push to another `UIViewController`, so I basically want the inner viewController to be a child of a `UINavigationController`. I know that you cannot change the content of a container view once it has been initialised (not directly anyways), so I've hit a wall. 
Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can nest a `UINavigationController` inside a `UIViewController` or do I need to rethink my approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heavily inspired by @7vikram7 I ended up with a container view that embedded a `UINavigationController` which had my *InnerViewController* as its root viewController:
[image: Screen dump of the basic storyboard setup]

In my *InnerViewController* I am now able to push to any `UIViewController`, and control my navigation stack, for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Hide the navigation bar
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    // Push to whatever viewController I want to
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myAwesomeViewController") as! AwesomeViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply take a `UINavigationController`.
Initialise it with your *InnerViewController*.

Now, add the `UINavigationController` as (*childViewController* + *addSubview* + *didMoveToParentViewController*) in the *OuterViewController*.

Now as the *InnerViewController* is located inside a `UINavigationController`. You can push whatever you want on the `UINavigationController`.